# Trouble with ArrayList get method

Tags: java, arraylist

Having an issue using the "get" method in the ArrayList class.

Main method is supposed to create a deck of cards in an ArrayList and then display all the cards.  I'm just looking for an explanation as to why I'm getting an error with "d.get(i)" while it is in my main method (game class).  If i use it in the deck class it works fine.

Game class:

```
package game;
import java.util.*;

public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*Card f = new Card(2,7);
    System.out.println(f.toString());*/

    Deck d = new Deck();
    int i = 0;

    while(i < 52)
    {
        //where error occurs:
        Card k = d.get(i);//get is underlined red
        System.out.println(d.toString());
        i++;
    }

}

}
```

Card class:

```
package game;

public class Card {

private int suit, value;
private String[] cardSuit = {"Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs"};
private String[] cardValue = {"Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10",
                               "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2"};

public Card(int cSuit, int cValue)
{
    suit = cSuit; 
    value = cValue;
}

public String toString()
{
    String cardInfo = cardValue[value] + " of " + cardSuit[suit];

    return cardInfo;
}

public int getValue()
{
    return value;

}

public int getSuit()
{
    return suit;
}


}
```

Deck class:

```
package game;
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

private ArrayList<Card> deck;

public Deck(){

    deck = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<13;j++){

        deck.add(new Card(i,j));

        }       
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your `Deck` class has a `get` method?

Comment: I don't think that. I'm thinking that I can use the get method from the arraylist class within main method

Comment: Then do that. Don't do `d.get(i)`. `d` is a `Deck`, not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: ok i gotchya, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement a getter for the `ArrayList` in the `Deck` class or add a get method to the `Deck` class and delegate to the `ArrayList`:

```
public Card get(int index) {
    return this.deck.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
Card k = d.getCards().get(i);
```

Of course, first you have to implement the `getCards()` method in the class `Deck`:

```
public ArrayList<Card> getCards() {
    return deck;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make a method to actually get your Card ArrayList:

```
package game;
import java.util.*;

public class Deck {

private ArrayList<Card> deck;

public Deck(){

    deck = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<13;j++){

        deck.add(new Card(i,j));

        }       
    }

}

public ArrayList<Card> getDeck() {
    return deck;
}
}
```